# Use RegExp in JS to replace a whole specific html tags with its whole contents

Tags: javascript, regex

Now I would like to use RegExp in JS to replace a whole specific html tags(for example; '<strong>') with its whole contents(innerHTML).

An Example:
Replace

```
<strong><u>hello</u></strong>
```

with

```
<u>hello</u>
```

Comment: you can get `<strong>` element content with `.innerHTML`, why do you need RegExp here?

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions is [extremely dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/382456).

Comment: I have try this; document.querySelector('tagParent').replaceChild(document.createTextNode(document.querySelector('strong').innerHTML),document.querySelector('strong')); is there any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) property of the element to its [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) should work fine here; no regexp needed.

`var parent = document.querySelector('tagParent');
parent.outerHTML = parent.innerHTML;`

Answer (score 0):

I have try this; document.querySelector('tagParent').replaceChild(document.createTextNode(documen‌​t.querySelector('strong').innerHTML),document.querySelector('strong'));
Is there any better way?